# In Postgres, how to select by a column of type UUID

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I have a DB table that someone else created, its PK is a single column of type 'uuid'. I'm struggling to perform a simple select by that column. Examples I have tried with no success:

`select from site where id = "9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0"`

`select from site where id = UUID('9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0')`

`select from site where id::text = '9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0'`

what's the right syntax?

Comment: The last two work just fine: http://rextester.com/XSTGL91416 `UUID('9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0')` is the same as `'9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0'::uuid`

Answer (score 13):

A colleague enlightened me: it was the double quotes around the string literal. The right syntax is:

`select from site where id = '9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0'`

I'm answering my own question, hoping that this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Yes indeed, and your problem was not specific to the UUID type you would have had problems with all other cases if you use double quotes. So, do not use double quotes for that :-) See the following resources for further explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql , https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html and http://blog.lerner.co.il/quoting-postgresql/

Comment: Be sure and mark your answer as correct - that will also help others find it (no points though :-) )

Comment: Under the hood, Postgres converts the filter in your query to `id = '9d4da323-4c20-360f-bd9b-ec54feec54f0'::uuid`. You can see this when you run your query prepended with `explain `.